# (C#) Table Layout Panel causing weird output

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, chat

I am trying to make a graphical chat like program with the following code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LogLoader();
        cellNo +=1;
        dateLoader(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"));
        if (datestamp.Text == DateTime.Today.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"))
        {
            dateLoader("Today");
        }
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(datestamp, 0, cellNo);
        LogCreator();
        inputBubbleLoader("Hello... Testing this", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(input,0,cellNo+1);
    }
    public void inputBubbleLoader(String inputText , String time)
    {
        Panel input = new Panel();

        inputLabel.Text = inputText;
        inputLabel.Font = new Font("Ariel", 10);
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(inputText,inputLabel.Font);
        inputLabel.Parent = input;
        inputLabel.Location = new Point(input.Location.X+5, input.Location.Y+5);
        timestamp1.Text = time;

        timestamp1.Parent = input;
        Size tsize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(timestamp1.Text, timestamp1.Font);
        timestamp1.Location = new Point(input.Location.X + input.Width - tsize.Width-5, input.Location.Y+input.Height-(tsize.Height)-5);

        inputLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(tableLayoutPanel1.Width, 0);
        input.AutoSize = true;
        inputLabel.AutoSize = true;
        timestamp1.AutoSize = true;
        cellNo += 1;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[cellNo].Height = input.Height;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[cellNo].SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(input, 0, cellNo);
    }
    public void dateLoader(string date)
    {
        datestamp.Text = date;

        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[cellNo].Height = datestamp.Height;
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[cellNo].SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize;
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(datestamp,0,cellNo);
    }

    public void LogLoader()
    {

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Attey\Desktop\LogSave.txt");
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (line.StartsWith("--"))
            {
                dateLoader(line.Substring(line.IndexOf("-- [[")+1));
            }
            else if (line.StartsWith("["))
            {
                inputBubbleLoader(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(": ")), line.Substring(line.IndexOf("["), 8));

            }              
        }
    }
}
```

The LogLoader doesn't load the written message but only the test message,
Although the program successfully writes on the text file.
The table layout have some minor/major changes every time I run the program

Comment: No one likes to answer code dumps. Especially when at least 60% of that code is absolutely unnecessary to demonstrate the problem. I recommend you to remove all the unnecessary GUI-related cruft, perhaps even turning it into a CUI. I am sure that you will find the problem if you do what I tell you now. Even if not - you will have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you can post here with clear conscience that you have done everything you can.

Comment: But the problem is in the GUI portion.
Thank you for telling though.
I have trimmed the post.

Comment: @SPSingh Have you actually made a MCVE, or have you just removed some code, so that the sample won't look so gross? Personally I won't bet on the former. Isolate the issue in as small code as possible. Sometimes it is even necessary to create the demonstration from scratch.

Comment: Alright I'll try my best on the next edit

Comment: Its MCVE now
Cannot reduce it more as I am not sure which portion is causing the problem

Comment: No, you can reduce it more. Most of the UI properties you set in `inputBubbleLoader` are unnecessary. Also I can't see where you create `inputLabel` and `timestamp1` - there is a high chance that you reuse the same controls with each new `Panel input`.

Comment: Thank you very much , I figured it out
I was assigning new values to those vars outside the loader